# Java App on Swisscom Cloud failing with OOM

Tags: java, jvm, cloud-foundry, tomcat8, swisscomdev

We have Java Application that is deployable on Swisscom Cloud.
Instance having 1.5 G of RAM.
We are using next params for CF to limit memory usage for this app.

```
[jre: { version: 1.8.0_+ }, memory_calculator: {memory_sizes: {stack: 228k}, 
memory_heuristics: {heap: 50, metaspace: 20, native: 50, stack: 10}}]
```

Under instance, when executing `ps -ef | grep java` we get:

```
-Xms611500K -XX:MetaspaceSize=244600K -Xmx611500K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=244600K -Xss228
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m 
-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=250m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointer
```

Unfortunately after some time our app process is killed ("Exit with status 137"). We tried different other settings for CF, but no luck. Despite the fact we limited used memory we are always running out of 1.5 Gigs of RAM.

```
    2016-11-10T14:31:08.34+0200 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 
72a197e9-e222-43b5-9828-9553c1d58315 payload: {"instance"=>"", "index"=>0, 
"reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) 
occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 137 (out of memory)\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", 
"crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1478781068233690142, 
"version"=>"ebfced51-9973-434b-8ec0-79a8caa86b3b"}
```

Before crash we were analyzing heap memory usage using New Relic and what we discovered you can see below:

[image: Used Heap memory]
[image: Used Non-Heap memory]
Here, around 4:30 happened `Exited with status 137 (out of memory)`. As you can see there were no exceeds of memory at all.

When I executed `top` command under cf instance before the crash I got next:

`7 vcap      10 -10 6160764 1.357g  22528 S  27.3  7.4   3:09.52 java`

What can be actually wrong? Because I see that java process actually used almost 1.4G of RAM, but from New Relic graphs there is no such big amount of memory used.

Comment: See here for exit codes: http://journal.thobe.org/2013/02/jvms-and-kill-signals.html When you say "...Despite the fact we limited used memory..." is this a limit in cloudfoundry? I guess it is killing your process if it uses too much memory. So you would also need to limit the memory in JVM

Comment: Limit memory in JVM using Xmx you mean? Yes I limited so.

Comment: I added more graphs after monitoring with New Relic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your application is crashing because the CF container believes it is using too much memory.  This assumption can be validated by looking at the crash events in "cf events" and ensuring they are OOM crashes.  Assuming it is the container that is crashing the application this is how I usually tune this situation.

The java_buildpack tries really hard to contain an application's memory use.  However, it seems there are still applications where the jvm finds ways to allocate memory outside of the configured options.

When I run into this issue the simplest way for me to tune the config is to simply continue increasing the "native" memory ratio and decreasing heap until the application stabilizes.  Native is the catch all bucket for anything the jvm may allocate that the buildpack doesn't manage.

I'd also remove the "heap:600m" config since that will only make the heuristic calculations more complex and potentially make increasing native percentage ineffective.

Comment: I second this suggestion.  You might even consider going one step further though.  Increase the memory limit of your application, but tune the JBP such it does not increase the heap / meta space limits.  The idea is to leave a ridiculously large amount of "native" memory (you can scale this back later), which acts like a buffer and gives your app free, unused memory.  If you bump it up enough, it'll prevent your app from crashing and you can then investigate (jmap, profiler, etc..) what is using more memory than you expect in your app (or maybe the JVM).

Comment: Oh, also make sure you use JBP 3.8+.  Some adjustments were made to the memory calculations in that version.  If you're stuck on an older version, you can `cf set-env <app-name> JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE [memory_calculator: { stack_threads: 300, memory_sizes: {stack: 228k}, memory_heuristics: {heap: 65, native: 15, stack: 10}}]'` to get the same changes.

Comment: Currently I am having next setup:

Reserved memory for CF instance - 1536m
JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: [jre: { version: 1.8.0_+ }, memory_calculator: {memory_sizes: {stack: 228k}, memory_heuristics: {heap: 50, native: 50, stack: 10}}]
JAVA_OPTS: -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=150m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers

Comment: I even configured Tomcat to use Direct Buffers with limits from JAVA_OPTS named XX:MaxDirectMemorySize.
Nothing helped, memory usage continues to grow.

Interesting thing that I see next when using jcmd summary command for the process:
Native Memory Tracking:
Total: reserved=1107812KB, committed=941036KB

But what I see when using top command differs:
7 vcap      10 -10 6037180 1.112g  22324 S   8.3  7.1   2:14.09 java  

Something like 941MB against 1.112, that I cannot explain at all.

Comment: If your app is leaking memory, then it will be killed or run into an OutOfMemory condition eventually. No configuration will fix that. The only option you have is to find the memory leak and fix it. If the memory usage is related to load, you might want to limit load. I don't think killing the JVM is a good option, since you loose the possibility to do some diagnostics, such as performing a HeapDump when you run into OutOfMemory.

Comment: Connected newrelic. Will provide graphs of how memory was used.

Comment: Added graphs from New Relic.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your application? Are there any native libraries you are using? Please understand that the Java HEAP is contained in the process HEAP but if some native library called from the JVM uses HEAP memory it is not part of the Java HEAP and therefor not part of the limit you are setting.

Comment: @EugeneGy 50 50 10 is odd since they're supposed to add up to 100%. :)  The buildpack should probably validate that.  Anyway, lets try and determine if you have some kind of odd native leak or something.  Try setting the config to "heap: 20, native: 70, stack: 10" and give your app 2G of memory how does your app respond?  Does it still die?  Does it take longer?  Do you get a different OOM Error?  maybe a Heap error instead?